# How to Create a Static SSRS Report without using a DataSet &DataSource

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, dsn

Tring to create a Static Report such that no DataSet/Datasource is used.
Inserted a Table with static values but preview is giving me error :

[image]

Any other Solution other than TextBox with Labels ?
Also read solutions like give `dataset to use SELECT '',but for that also we need to specify DSN.
Solution which Iam looking out for Static data with no DataSet/Datasource.Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

In short, you cannot use a tablix (table/matrix) without a dataset. However, you can create a dataset that uses a datasource that does not require any kind of external connection.

Create a new report.

Create a dataset and choose to use an embedded datasource.

Create a new datasource and choose "enter data" as the type, click ok.

Nww click "query designer" and enter anything in the table presented.

You can now point your tablix to this dataset but ignore it's contents completely.

Alternatively, you could the use query design to actually enter your data and then present it like anything else.

Here's a short GIF to demo the process

[image]